# Auslander-Reiten sequences where irreducible morphisms are all epi/mono

Tags: rt.representation-theory, modules, quivers

Let's work in the setting of modules over an Artin algebra $A$, or a finite-dimensional $k$-algebra $A$, or if you like, modules over a connected quiver $Q$ without oriented cycles.

Let $M$ be such a module, and suppose $M$ is indecomposable and non-injective.  Then $M$ fits into an A-R sequence,
$$0 \rightarrow M \xrightarrow{(f_i)} \bigoplus_i E_i \rightarrow N \rightarrow 0,$$
where $N = \tau^- M$, and the $E_i$ are the indecomposable summands of the middle term. We write $f_i \colon M \rightarrow E_i$ for the maps to each summand.   These $f_i$ are irreducible morphisms, hence mono or epi.

Is there a nice condition under which all the $f_i$ are epi?  This happens, e.g., for some modules for zigzag quivers of type $A_n$.  But I can't find any sort of general treatment.  I'm new to the whole quiver and Auslander-Reiten theory, so perhaps I can't find the right words to search for.

Comment: Do you really mean *all* of the $f_i$ are *surjective*, at the same time?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean.  It happens sometimes.  E.g., take a zigzag quiver with even numbers pointing to odd, like 0 -> 1 <- 2 -> 3 <- 4 -> 5 <- 6 -> 7 <- 8.   Take an indec module like the interval module [2,6].  I think the irreducible morphisms starting at [2,6] are all epis... they have targets [2,4] and [4,6].   At the same time [2,6] injects into [2,4] \oplus [4,6].

Comment: Thanks; just feels a bit counterintuitive!  Sorry, I don't have an answer to the question - except a gut feeling that this might well be pretty rare. It doesn't happen for linearly oriented type A, right?